# <a> tag refreshes my asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an  tag within my listview to direct the user to the profile page

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ownerID") %>"></a>
```

The profile page works as I can load it myself. However when I hover over the  tag it shows the the correct link that it'll be directed to, but when I click on it, it just refreshes the current page, I've used the  tag the same way in different pages and it works but for some reason it does not work here.

What could be the reason why?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser debugger network window to see what's happening?

Comment: what is your current URL when having this page and did you checked the network in the development console of your browser ?

Comment: @dman2306 Just a quick question, does it matter if I wrap the <a> tag around an ASP button?

Comment: Can you post any code wrapping that <a> and the current URL.

Comment: Have you used this tag in `profile.aspx`?

Comment: Do you have output caching turned on server-side that doesn't depend on the parameters passed?

Comment: That button is hard to find without a Text inside it. You might be clicking the wrong link. Just saying, cause if it works in other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try this anchor tag, HREF should be in single quote.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href='profile.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ownerID")%>'>For Test</a>
```